# Trouble installing PhoneGap - No compatible version found: JSONStream@'>=1.0.3 < 2.0.0'

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to install PhoneGap with `npm install -g phonegap` or `npm install -gf phonegap`, I get this error message:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.0
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: JSONStream@'>=1.0.3 <2.0.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.0.0","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.3.0","0.3.1","0.3.2","0.3.3","0.4.0","0.4.1","0.4.2","0.4.3","0.4.4","0.5.0","0.6.0","0.6.1","0.6.2","0.6.3","0.6.4","0.7.0","0.7.1","0.8.0","0.7.2","0.7.3","0.7.4","0.8.1","0.8.2","0.8.3","0.8.4","0.9.0","0.10.0"]
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'deps-sort'
npm ERR! notarget
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

It is a temporary issue due to a bad configuration, that will be fixed pretty soon I believe.

In the meantime, you can use the version 4 via `sudo npm install -g phonegap@4.0.0-0.22.7` and update later today when it will be fixed.

Comment: If you're using cordova, you may encounter the same error. Dropping back to 4.1.2 appears to work. `sudo npm install -g cordova@4.1.2`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me Thanks.

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap@4.0.0-0.22.7
```

and for cordova

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@4.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

---

The issue is resolved now per:
https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream/issues/68

You should be able to update/install.